# Pass a forms' input as parameter to .php file in url using window.open()

Tags: php, html, window.open

Would like to use window.open() to pass an email address as a parameter appended to the url, but am getting hung up. This is what's getting returned

> http://app.gogodriver.com/SignupPage.php?email=[object%20HTMLInputElement]

Function:

```
function open_app(tryitemail)
{
    window.open("http://app.gogodriver.com/SignupPage.php?email="+tryitemail, "_blank","width=450, height=650");    
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="tryitfree">                                       
    <input class="input" type="text" name="tryitemail" placeholder="Email" size="25" />
    <input type="image" src="images/go-button.png" id="TryItButton" value="email" onClick="open_app(tryitemail)">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are sending the input element, not its value. You should do this:

```
<input type="image" src="images/go-button.png" id="TryItButton" value="email" onClick="open_app(tryitemail.value)">
```